Is Definition of Convex(concave upward) functions flawed?

The definition: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Convex_function&wprov=rarw1
From what I've understood, it says that if a function is concave upward in an interval, then the function is either below or touches the line joining the extremes of the function's value for the interval. For example, the quadratic is concave upward here because it always lies below the line joining the extreme points:

However, consider the following function between the marked intervals:

Although it seems to satisfy the definition of a convex function, clearly from the second derivative test there exists a point of inflection (green point in the image) between the interval. In fact, one can come up with many such functions which always lie below a line but change their concavity many times.
Is there something I've misunderstood in the definition?


In the definition of convexity, it is required that for each $x,y$ in your interval $(a,b)$, the function lies entirely under the line connecting $f(x)$ and $f(y)$, in other words
$$ f\left(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y\right)\le \lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y) $$As you can clearly see, this condition is not true in your second graph, since if we choose $x=a$, then for $y$ sufficiently close to $x$ (for example in the point of inflection) the graph is above the line.
